# Is there an example of the "align" function from The Little Schemer?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

In chapter 9 of *The Little Schemer*:

```lisp
(define align
  (lambda (pora)
    (cond ((atom? pora) pora)
          ((a-pair? (first pora)) (align (shift pora)))
          (else (build (first pora)
                       (align (second pora)))))))
```

Most of the functions in the book have examples, and the examples are usually explained in detail, but not this function.

I don't understand how to use this function, and so I can't understand the functions that follow. I can't find examples of this function on the web.

Could you show me some examples?

Comment: (align 1). (align '((1 2) 3)). (align '(1)).

Comment: Still do not get what was the intention of this function (except to make the comparison with `kee-looking` from the previous page).

`(align '((1 2) 3))` will return exactly the same thing that `(shift '((1 2) 3))`, in this case `'(1 (2 3))`

Why is it called align? It doesn't seem to align anything actually oO

Answer (score 1):

I have found this repository with both the code and some examples:

> https://github.com/viswanathgs/The-Little-Schemer/blob/master/ch-09-and-again-and-again-and-again.ss

The examples for align:

```lisp
(align '(a b))                     ; (a b)
(align '((a b) c))                 ; (a (b c))
(align '((a b) (c d)))             ; (a (b (c d)))
(align '((a (b c)) (((d e) f) g))) ; (a (b (c (d (e (f g))))))
```